# Can you test for browser support for -moz-linear-gradient?

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

I would like to use feature detection to tell whether the user's version of Firefox supports the CSS style value `-moz-linear-gradient`. (This was added in Gecko 1.9.2. Version 3.6 of Firefox uses this.)

I can't use `document.body.style.mozLinearGradient` (or something similar) because `-moz-linear-gradient` is not a style property but a style value.

Does anyone know how to test for this without using version numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how, but [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) (a nice little feature-detection script) appears to do it.

I guess you could create an (offscreen?) element, set that as it's style, and then poke around in the DOM to see if the browser successfully applied it?

Comment: It looks like that's what Modernizr does. It creates a DOM element but doesn't add it to the page.

Answer (score 2):

Just assign it as style value and check afterwards if it is there.

Kickoff example:

```
function supportsMozLinearGradient() {
    var element = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; // Just grab an "invisible" element.
    var oldstyle = element.style.background; // Backup old style.
    try {
        element.style.background = '-moz-linear-gradient(top, black, white)';
    } catch(e) {
        // Ignore failures.
    }
    var supports = element.style.background.indexOf('-moz-linear-gradient') > -1; // Did it accept?
    element.style.background = oldstyle; // Restore old style.
    return supports;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check for `-moz-background-size` (which was introduced in Firefox v3.6). The inference won't be picked up by other browsers since the property is prefixed.

```
if ('MozBackgroundSize' in document.body.style)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how MooTools detects Gecko (Firefox) engine (I'm "paraphrasing" slightly)

```
gecko = (!document.getBoxObjectFor && window.mozInnerScreenX == null) ? false : ((document.getElementsByClassName) ? 19 : 18)
```

So if it's FF it'll return 19 or 18, I believe 19 is 3.x and 18 is 2.x

And apparently FF3.6 stopped supporting `document.getBoxObjectFor`, so to detect 3.6 I basically do

```
isFF36 = gecko && !document.getBoxObjectFor
```

Works like a charm from a few tests I did.

If you're not using MooTools you can probably combine the two into one statement that would return something like `false` or `'ff'` or `'f36'` but I'm too lazy to work through that logic :)

Comment: Gah! Nooo! Feature detection, not browser detection! 

Otherwise you're setting yourself up for endless maintenance updates as new versions/variants of the rendering engine appear. What if the next gecko removes or changes support for whatever you're relying upon?