# How can I detect via JavaScript if browser supports CSS3 media queries and CSS3 gradient?

Tags: css, media-queries, gradient

How can I detect via JavaScript if browser supports CSS3 media queries?

How can I detect via JavaScript if browser supports CSS3 gradient?

Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

Cracking open [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) (which can test for media queries) we see it uses the `window.matchMedia` ([MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.matchMedia)) function.  We can check in plain old vanilla JS to see if this function exists (Modernizr is *really* awesome, but sometimes you just want a brick, not a house):

```
function mediaQueriesSupported()
{
    if(typeof window.matchMedia != "undefined" || typeof window.msMatchMedia != "undefined")
    {
        // alert("media queries are supported!");
        return true;
    }else{
        // alert("no media query support :(");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Or more elegantly:

```
function mediaQueriesSupported()
{
    return (typeof window.matchMedia != "undefined" || typeof window.msMatchMedia != "undefined");
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PzegV/10/)

I've tested in the following browsers that support media queries, all correctly returned true:

- Safari Mobile
- Chrome 26

I've tested in the following browsers that do not support media queries, all correctly returned false:

- IE 7

As for gradient support detection, there are some great answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853507/simple-css-gradient-detection) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253519/can-you-test-for-browser-support-for-moz-linear-gradient).  Effectively you're just setting the property and then testing for it after the fact.  Browsers will throw out junk or unsupported CSS properties.

**EDIT:**

Niet has an excellent answer to this problem over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13665697/i-need-an-easy-way-to-detect-css3-media-query-support-using-jquery/17203032#17203032), similar to my suggestions for gradient detection.  It's not pure Javascript (it requires a very small amount of CSS) but it's an absolutely fool-proof method.

Comment: IE9 support the CSS media queries, but doesn't have the `matchMedia` JavaScript method.

Comment: @Etienne I've edited my answer to cover IE9.  I don't actually have a computer ready to test 9, though, so it may not work.  The change brings my code closer to Modernizr's `mq` function (which checks to see if a browser supports a particular media query before trying to run it).  My JSFiddle is also updated if anyone wants to try it out (for comparison, [here is the old JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3vbNb/))

Comment: @Sandy I am actually getting back the function and not a true or false back from the elegantly solution :) Its all good thought I used this instead:`mediaQueriesSupported = function () {
  return (window.matchMedia || window.msMatchMedia) ? true : false;
 };`

Comment: @sebastian.derossi I'm reading over this question again and I think I see the problem.  If window.matchMedia is not defined, but window.msMatchMedia is, window.msMatchMedia will return, not true or false.  Good catch!

Comment: This code gives "not supported" for IE9, although it does support media queries. Seems to work fine for other browsers.